# Hibernate doesn't save object

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I've created table ip and created mapping files by wizards on NetBeans 8.2.
Thats the ip schema:
[image]

and added to  hibernate config

```
<property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>
```

but when I'm trying to insert something to table query doesn't executes.
On other tables it works.

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Ip info = new Ip();
    info.setAsn("aaaa");
    info.setCity("aaaa");
    info.setCountry("aa");
    info.setIp(213213);
    info.setIsp("aaaa");
    info.setLat(44.4);
    info.setLon(55.5);
    info.setOrg("aaaa");
    info.setRegion("aaaa");
    session.save(info);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to invoke `session.flush()`.

Autocommit it's about pushing data to Database without invoking `save` method.

Comment: THANK YOU so much

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate only  the operation included in `transacion` will be sent to the database.
so the correct code is:

```
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
 Ip info = new Ip();
info.setAsn("aaaa");
info.setCity("aaaa");
info.setCountry("aa");
info.setIp(213213);
info.setIsp("aaaa");
info.setLat(44.4);
info.setLon(55.5);
info.setOrg("aaaa");
info.setRegion("aaaa");
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(info);
t.commit();
```

Doing that hibernte will send the insert to database, it is not immediately (it is quite so) to be sure that it is sent immediately you have to flush the session with `session.flush()` but that is a plus
hope this help
r.